# If I remove 20% of the train examples, my CV and train score improves, how can I find the reason why?

Tags: machine-learning, train

I have a small dataset - several thousands examples with a lot of features, a lot of them have a lot of zeros. If I remove 20% of examples from the end of the dataset - my CV and train(on changed train set) score goes up.

My theory is that there are a few really bad examples spread out there in these 20%
How can I find the examples that influence the training and remove only them and leave the good ones? removing 20% from the front of the dataset does not improve the score to this point.

One of the clues may be that when I remove examples from the end - they are sorted in a particular way.

It improves the result not only on CV, but on the the test that is outside my train/CV split as well

UPD1:
Here are some roc auc stats
all sets are shuffled during cv, it's a binary classification task

Each iteration below used different randomization before passing to same random seed CV/train
Computed on 10 runs of train and cv(10 folds each):

```
Full and random

Final train mean: 0.5886
Final train std: 0.0030
Final cv mean: 0.5661
Final cv std: 0.0040

-20% and only after random

Final train mean: 0.6036
Final train std: 0.0047
Final cv mean: 0.5791
Final cv std: 0.0056

random and only then -20% from the end

Final train mean: 0.5926
Final train std: 0.0039
Final cv mean: 0.5682
Final cv std: 0.0052

NO random and -20% from the end

Final train mean: 0.6048
Final train std: 0.0000
Final cv mean: 0.5827
Final cv std: 0.0000

NO random and FULL

Final train mean: 0.5955
Final train std: 0.0000
Final cv mean: 0.5620
Final cv std: 0.0000
```

Plot of CV for runs above
[image]

I also run a test where I remove 1.5% from the set and train, nor randomization during removal, just remove 0%-1.5% interval then 1.5%-3% interval etc
Here's the plot of train score during removal

[image]

Comment: Can you please try to bootstrap your metrics so there is some quantification of the variance involved?

Comment: @usεr11852 could you please elaborate on what I need to do?

Comment: Resample your data multiple times and run the evaluation procedure you have in each sample independently. Then get the individual performance index from each sample and treat those as the (empirical) distribution of your  performance index. Then check what is the variability of it.

Comment: @usεr11852 I've added some stats for 10 runs and different dataset changes

Comment: Sorry can you describe exactly what: "random and only then -20% from the end" and "-20% and only after random" mean? In general, as soon as you randomise the "final cv mean" is immediately lower than the" final train mean" (as expected more or less) showing that yo do not overfit. The fact that "full and random CV" and "random and only then -20% from the end" are now similar shows that indeed there was some structure in the ordering of the examples. That violates our assumption of having IID sample. The fact that the metrics became better does not mean that we get a better classifier. (Cont.)

Comment: You might want to either use the reasoning behind the ordering of the data as an additional feature or ignore the ordering altogether and go with the full data. For all we know that "lower 20%" are the most interesting cases and you just exclude them just predicting trivial cases.

Comment: But what if by trying to predict these interesting cases, I'm breaking the performance of the classifier on the trivial ones and the trivial ones are more prevalent(have no idea)? by "random and only then -20% from the end" I've meant ```randomize(data)[:data_size*0.8]``` and "-20% and only after random" ```randomize(data[:data_size*0.8])``` also thanks for the feature suggestion. I'll try it. but why is such drastic difference between throwing away random 20% and 20% at the end... would it look like this if these 20% had a slightly different distribution from the rest of the data?

Comment: Yes, you are potentially massing up two different populations. Have you done any EDA on that dataset?